# IBM Bluemix Secure gateway / public access

Tags: ibm-cloud, secure-gateway

Should I be able to setup secure gateway to be able to connect to my on-prem SQL server DB, using SQL Server Management Studio on my laptop from home (not on prem)?

Comment: The question is too broad and not programming-related. The answer depends on your capabilities, the IT security policies and many more.

Answer (score 0):

You don't "have to" use the secure gateway in order for your application on the cloud to see your local db. You could simply give your application the public ip (and port) of the local machine and they should work fine.

It is however a good practise to use the Secure Gateway service as it can ensure the security of the local-to-cloud communication. Make sure to have a look at the documentation to learn how the service works - https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/SecureGateway/secure_gateway.html